# Apply bootstrap button group style to angularjs button directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created an angularjs directive `my-button` to wrap a button with some logic, so the template is something like:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary"
        ng-click="ctrl.onClick()"
        ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled">
  {{ctrl.message}}
</button>
```

Now I want to display a group of `my-button` instances using bootstrap:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <my-button is-disabled="false" message="Button1"></my-button>
  <my-button message="Button2"</my-button>
  <my-button message="Button3"></my-button>
</div>
```

The problem is, Bootstrap won't apply the group style as it declares CSS such that the `btn` is the child of the `btn-group` e.g.

```
.btn-group > .btn {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

How can I allow my directive to be used in a button group as it is?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can just put the `btn-group` class on the directive, so as follows:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <my-button class="btn-group" is-disabled="false" message="Button1"></my-button>
  <my-button class="btn-group" message="Button2"</my-button>
  <my-button class="btn-group" message="Button3"></my-button>
</div>
```

Because Bootstrap has e.g this:

```
.btn-group > .btn-group {
  float: left;
}
```

But I'd like to know if there's a better/cleaner way?